# How to change mouse pointer to hour glass on button click in web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mouse-cursor

How to change the mouse pointer to hour glass on button click and back to pointer after loading data in an asp.net web application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple solution is to use JavaScript...

```
function doHourglass()
{
  document.body.style.cursor = 'wait';
}
```

```
<body onbeforeunload="doHourglass();" onunload="doHourglass();"><body
```

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8243/Hourglass-cursor-for-Web-ASP-NET-pages

I found this article by searching for "ASP.NET Cursor" it was the first result.